# How do you add an imageset to the tab bar icon in the controller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image

How do you programmatically in obj-c set the icon of the tab bar to an imagemage-set?  In storyboard you just have to list its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one of the view controllers that is in the tab bar controller, you need to do this:

```
for (UITabBarItem *tbi in self.tabBarController.tabBar.items) {
        tbi.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageNameInImageSet"];
}
```

Use index in the loop, or use the tab bar item title, or whatever you want to choose the correct image.

Comment: Also be sure to not include the extension (.png, .jpg, etc) as Xcode will take care of that for you

Comment: Thanks, this works.  Why does it lose reference to the image being set in storyboard after setting a custom controller class?  It doesn't lose reference to the tab bar name that's being set in the storyboard..

Comment: @TimNuwin Hmm, I don't think it'd lose reference to the image.

Comment: Then why do I have to set the img + selected image again programmatically, even though it was set in storyboard?

Comment: @TimNuwin My guess is either: one of your code or third party code is overriding the Storyboard image, or your view controller is not loading the correct tab bar controller from your storyboard. In theory, if you set the image in Storyboard, you wouldn't have to set it again programatically.